# Using Java getResource when resources are bound by paths

Tags: java, xsd

I've been on this problem for some time but still can't nail it. I have a Java project using XML Schema files which are joined by imports. All of them are in a valid resource directory at the same level, so I use something like:

```
<xs:import schemaLocation="types.xsd"/>
```

in file *schema.xsd* to import one from another. Now, when I grab the schema by

```
getResourceAsStream(absolutePath)
```

to validate it I can load it all right; problem is that the validator will then look for the imported *types.xsd* in the main project directory rather than the resource directory. Is there any way to solve this without having to hard-code a relative (build structure dependent) path in schemaLocation?

Comment: What Validator are you using? Also, it looks like you are passing the file stream to the validator, so it doesn't have a way to know where the file was located. Maybe there is a setter or another constructor which takes a File, or a String path ?

Comment: Yes, passing a String did the trick! It actually seems very simple now, thanks a lot! ;)
I was using `javax.xml.validation.Validator` which was SAX in my config.

Answer (score 0):

Your schema, including imports, should be valid for whoever reads it. schemaLocation is defined by XSD, not by Java. Accordingly, any imported schema shoud be addressed with relative or absolute path, not by putting it on the Java classpath.

Answer (score 0):

In Java XML APIs, there is always an API to teach the parser/validator/transformer how to resolve external references:

- For SAXParsers, there is the `org.xml.sax.EntityResolver`.
- For Transformers, there is the `javax.xml.transform.URIResolver`.
- And for Validators, there is the `org.w3c.dom.ls.LSResourceResolver`.

Notice that all of them are *interfaces*, so you can make your own implementation and then pass it through the corresponding setter method.

In your case, it should be something like this:

```
    Validator validator=createValidator();
    validator.setResourceResolver(new LSResourceResolver() {
         public LSInput resolveResource(String publicId, String systemId, String baseURI) {
             File file=new File(resourcesRoot, systemId);
             return new MyLsInput(file);
         }
    );
    validator.validate(source, result);
```

(*MyLsInput* stands for some user implementation of `org.w3c.dom.ls.LSInput`, which is a very long interface).